# How to remove the DC offset from the output of my op-amp integrator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator, miller-integrator

I am trying to simulate an active integrator for Rogowski coil based current sensing application. The following is  my circuit.

Rogowski coil with active integrator:

[image: Rogowski Coil with active Integrator]

The current to be sensed is passed through inductor L2 which is mutually coupled with the Rogowski coil with coupling co-efficient 0.0192, which is passed through an active integrator circuit.

Following is the input and output.

[image: Input and Output]

As seen from the images, the input varies from 0-40A,but the output varies from -30mV to 20mV. I want it to vary from 0 to 50mV. How can that be done? What is the reason of this -30mv DC shift?

**EDIT 1:** I have added the waveform of the input to the integrator for clarity.

I(L1) is the current but which gets differentiated and scaled. V(integin) is an AC signal i.e it has an average value of 0V or no DC component.

[image: Input to the integrator]

**EDIT 2:** If I input a sinusoid to the same integrator then I don't have a DC shift.

Why is that happening?

Sinusoid to integrator:

[image: Sinusoid to integrator]

Output of sine:

[image: Output of sine]

Comment: Note how in **both** traces, the lower horizontal parts of the traces are **shorter** than the upper horizontal parts. This means that the **average value** of your green trace isn't exactly 20 A. I would take a step back and do a **DC operating point** analysis to look at all the DC voltages **when there is no signal**. Are all DC voltages what they should be? No => fix that first. Yes => apply a proper signal with exactly 50% Duty cycle.

Comment: No it is not, the duty cycle is 0.7, but this is not the input to the integrator, the input is the derivative of this signal, which has an average =0.

Comment: *No it is not, the duty cycle is 0.7* Then your signal already has a DC offset so why do you expect the circuit to remove that offset?

Comment: Please refer to the edit. The differentiated signa which is the input to the integrator does not have a DC component.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see Miller, Deboo or any other active integrator here. What I see, is a passive RC integrating circuit buffered by a non-inverting amplifier. Maybe C1 is the integrating capacitor here and this is another kind of active integrator unknown for me?

Answer (score 2):

> *What is the reason of this -30mv DC shift?*

The [input offset voltage for your op-amp](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/62689f.pdf) is +/- 0.2 mV typically but can be as high as +/- 2.5 mV. Given that your circuit has a DC gain of 201, you might see anything from +/- 40 mV to +/- 0.5 volts DC offset on the output.

Clearly, if the offset you see is only 30 mV then your model doesn't adequately represent typical values in the data sheet.

Comment: How can we mitigate it?

Comment: Choose an op-amp with a much better control of its input offset voltage or, manually adjust it to zero with a potentiometer circuit.

Comment: @SambeetPanigrahi [Take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what motivates folk to give free advice.

Comment: I understand the input offset voltage might be a possible cause, but when I give a AC signal(centered at 0) to the integrator, I get back the integrated signal without any DC offset. If the reason is drift ,I should get the same DC shift.

Comment: All I can tell you is that with a sine wave and a real circuit, you will get a big offset due to the input offset error. I note that your sinewave signal is a much lower frequency and your graph response is over a much longer timescale than your original transient response. I also note that the sinewave you applied has no average DC offset.

Comment: @SambeetPanigrahi are we done here now? Are there any residual concerns?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an integrator which does not "derive", use "integrator" with some special "reset offset" drift capabilities. As AD8628.

Comment: AD8628 has a gain bandwidth product of 2 MHz. But I want a upto 200MHz gain bandwidth product..

Comment: I did not see this constraint ... ? In this case, i see an alternative "integrator" with a synchronized "integrated reset" of the offset, with the use of a fast sample/hold circuitry an probably some switches ...

Comment: An if you can "change" time ... with some synchronized sampling, you can also make a frequency down-converter ... as a controlled "aliazing" ...